# Why default constructor is not called while deserialization process?

Tags: java, serialization

```
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.ser"));
TestClass tc = (TestClass)is.readObject();
```

I get the object of TestClass after deserialization but TestClass default constructor is not called. As per my understanding
there are two ways to create object i.e either with new operator or TestClass.class.newInstance(). Both calls the default constructor.

Looks like deserialization process creates the object not with about two methods thats why default constructor is not called.
Question is how deserialization creates the object ?

Another point is if TestClass extends BaseTestClass and  BaseTestClass does not implements serialization ,
constructor of BaseTestClass is called but not TestClass. Why so ? I am sure there will be some logical reason behind it.
But i am not getting it?

Comment: What if class doesn't have default (non argument) constructor? Which constructor should be called then? How deserialization process should decide if there will be few constructors?

Comment: Became that's the way they designed it. Unless you get a JDK author responding, all you will get here is more or less uninformed opinion. Off topic.

Comment: It's internal implementation of JAVA and you don't need to bother about it. If interested then dig the source code of [ObjectInputStream#readObject()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java#ObjectInputStream.readObject%28%29).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth reading [Java Object Serialization Specification: 3 - Object Input Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html) where `readObject` method is described in details along with step by step explanation.

#### How it works?

An instance of the class is allocated. The instance and its handle are added to the set of known objects.

The contents restored appropriately:

1. For serializable objects, *the no-arg constructor for the first non-serializable supertype is run*.

   - For serializable classes, the fields are initialized to the default value appropriate for its type.
   - Then the fields of each class are restored by calling class-specific `readObject` methods, or if these are not defined, by calling the `defaultReadObject` method.
   - Note that *field initializers and constructors are not executed for serializable classes during deserialization*.
   - In the normal case, the version of the class that wrote the stream will be the same as the class reading the stream. In this case, all of the supertypes of the object in the stream will match the supertypes in the currently-loaded class.
   - If the version of the class that wrote the stream had different supertypes than the loaded class, the `ObjectInputStream` must be more careful about restoring or initializing the state of the differing classes.
   - It must step through the classes, matching the available data in the stream with the classes of the object being restored. Data for classes that occur in the stream, but do not occur in the object, is discarded.
   - For classes that occur in the object, but not in the stream, the class fields are set to default values by default serialization.
2. For externalizable objects, the no-arg constructor for the class is run and then the `readExternal` method is called to restore the contents of the object.

---

Sample code to understand fist point **For serializable objects, the no-arg constructor for the first non-serializable supertype is run.**

Sample code;

```
class TestClass1 {
    public TestClass1() {
        System.out.println("TestClass1");
    }
}

class TestClass2 extends TestClass1 implements Serializable {
    public TestClass2() {
        System.out.println("TestClass2");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Object construction via calling new keyword");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("resources/dummy.dat"));
    out.writeObject(new TestClass2());

    System.out.println("Object construction via readObject method");
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("resources/dummy.dat"));
    TestClass2 tc = (TestClass2) is.readObject();
}
```

output:

```
Object construction via calling new keyword
TestClass1
TestClass2

Object construction via readObject method
TestClass1
```

Comment: Good answer, better than mine, but you could try to explain more directly how does it happens that the object is created without running its constructor - because this is exactly what the OP seems to want to understand.

Comment: @BartoszKP I think its somewhat happened in `defaultReadObject` method. Let me discover it more.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this relates to `Externalizable` classes, not `Serializable`, as correctly indicated by [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) in the comments below. [Answer posted by Braj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096194/2642204) shows a code sample for `Serializable`.

---

First of all, note the difference between a default constructor and a no-arg constructor. Default constructor is a no-arg constructor generated if you don't provide any other constructor.

`ObjectInputStream` requires that a class has a no-arg constructor, here is a code sample that demonstrates it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
  static class Test implements Externalizable
  {
    //public Test() {}

    public Test(int x)
    {
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)
        throws IOException
    {
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    Test t = new Test(0);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
    oos.writeObject(t);
    oos.close();

    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    t = (Test)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
  }
}
```

Produces:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: Ideone$Test; no valid constructor
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:147)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:755)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
>       at Ideone.main(Main.java:36)

Demo on Ideone: http://ideone.com/yPpJrb

When you uncomment the no-arg constructor, it works fine. And it will also work fine when you'll remove the provided one-argument constructor - because then, the default constructor will be generated.

Comment: What is the difference between `default cosntructor` and `no-arg constructor`?

Comment: @Braj I've added the explanation.

Comment: But both are `no-arg constructor` at all.

Comment: It is true that `Externalizable` interface requires default constructor to deserialization, but `Serializable` doesn't (which I think question is about).

Comment: @Braj But they are not the same thing, and what is required is no-arg, not default.

Comment: @Pshemo Oh, you're right... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Bad luck because the question is about Serializable, not Externalizable. And a default constructor *is* a no-args constructor. This is a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @EJP Saying that a *default constructor is required* is wrong, because it suggests that you aren't allowed to write any constructors. But you can provide a no-arg constructor (which is *not* a *default constructor*, because its not generated) and it will suffice. So there is a difference.

Comment: @EJP Actually default constructor has same visibility as class visibility. In other words default constructor of class with default (package) visibility has also default (package) visibility.

Comment: @Bartosz As I didn't say a default constructor is required, I have no idea why you are addressing that comment to me.

Comment: @EJP I was explaining why I did put this distinction in my answer, because that's what OP seems to suggest. Whether anyone said directly that it's required is not a point here anyway, the point is that default and no-arg are NOT the same thing as you suggest. One example difference is that when you say "default constructor is required" it's not the same as "no-arg constructor is required". So there is a difference, quite important one. And you said there is no difference - hope that's clear now :)

Comment: As I did not utter the phrase 'default default constructor is required', which has no applicability or indeed meaning in Java, I still have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @EJP I have no idea why are you still talking about the "required" thing, as I've already indicated that it's not the point. Maybe I've misunderstood the OP, nevermind - just skip the "required" example if you don't like. But the fact is that the OP speaks about *default* constructors, when they are not relevant here - *no-arg* constructors are. And they are NOT the same thing :)

Comment: I have no idea why you are talking about 'required' either. I didn't say it. Nobody has said it except you. I suggest you confine yourself to what I did say, starting with the irrelevance of your answer to the question.

Comment: @EJP Well I've explained it to you just now, and I admitted that maybe I misunderstood the OP, and "required" is irrelevant here (but note that "default" is irrelevant as well). Perhaps we find different aspects of this conversation important - I was rather focusing on your "This is a distinction without a difference." nonsense.

Comment: It isn't 'nonsense'. A public no-args constructor generated by the compiler is indistinguishable in all respects from one written by the user. Your answer remains irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP Let me rephrase this, for the last time: That's true that they are indistinguishable if you look at them compiled. But they are notions on a different level. *default* is a description of **how** the constructor is being created, *no-args* is **what** kind of constructor it is in terms of "arity". That's the **difference** from practical point of view: *no-args* written by the user is something always present, *default* will be present only sometimes. The difference is in their origin, and conditions of their existence, so they're not the same "in all respects" as you claim. Bye :)

Answer (score 0):

from the oracle document

> Reading an object from the ObjectInputStream is analogous to creating a new object. Just as a new object's constructors are invoked in the order from the superclass to the subclass, an object being read from a stream is deserialized from superclass to subclass. The readObject or readObjectNoData method is called instead of the constructor for each Serializable subclass during deserialization.

so in nutshell it should call readObject() method in the hierarchy from super class to subclass. which will only present if all super class implements serializable interface, otherwise superclasse's default constructor is invoked.
so serializable

> Each subclass of a serializable object may define its own readObject method. If a class does not implement the method, the default serialization provided by defaultReadObject will be used. When implemented, the class is only responsible for restoring its own fields, not those of its supertypes or subtypes.